IP Whitelisting in (AKS) Kubernetes / ingress-nginx
Hello anyone who reads this,
I'm looking for a way to restrict access to a publically exposed service (type LoadBalancer) at 234.234.234.234:1234 to a specific trusted IP at 123.123.123.123.
The way to do this seems to be via
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 123.123.123.123/32
as described in articles such as this: https://medium.com/@maninder.bindra/using-nginx-ingress-controller-to-restrict-access-by-ip-ip-whitelisting-for-a-service-deployed-to-bd5c86dc66d6
However, this runs into a problem because the default externalTrafficPolicy being set to "Cluster" obfuscates the sender IP to some local bs even for the bloody Ingress controller.
The solution to this appears to be to set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy to Local, but I'm not sure about the ramifications of that since it changes the entire way of addressing pods and I've read some posts about performance issues with this approach.
There is also the problem that the resource in question already exists and I'd have to recreate it fully, apparently. Every post I've read on this seems to assume your resource doesn't exist yet.
I wonder if there is a way to lift the source IP obfuscation without a change as large-looking as that.

Thank you, the structure is a bit confusing and I'm not sure how they are exactly interlinked. Interestingly, there seems to be a posting restriction for new users common between the two... "You can only post once every 40 minutes."

To whitelist an IP address using the Nginx Ingress controller while maintaining the original client IP, setting externalTrafficPolicy to Local is typically the simplest approach.

It does work. I just hope it won't break anything else somewhere.
I found a quite good article on the trade-offs in the meantime: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/7028639 - if it doesn't work with "cluster", I might have to just test whether any packet drop problems will occur.

"Setting the externalTrafficPolicy to Local comes with potential downsides such as Load Distribution: Traffic is only sent to nodes with relevant pods or in case of pod failures, the service won't reroute traffic to other nodes unless a relevant pod is available on those nodes."
- Arko
This explanation resolved my doubts about using externalTrafficPolicy: Local in my specific use case.

To implement IP whitelisting in a public Kubernetes service with the Nginx Ingress controller, you need to configure the externalTrafficPolicy to Local to preserve the client's IP address. By default, the externalTrafficPolicy is set to Cluster, which means that traffic from the client is routed to any node in the cluster, and this can obfuscate the original client IP address.
To retain the client's IP address, set the externalTrafficPolicy to Local for your LoadBalancer service:
example
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 1234
    targetPort: 5678
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local

This setting ensures that external traffic is routed directly to the nodes where the pods are running, preserving the client's IP address.

You can update an existing service by applying this configuration, or you can patch the service using
kubectl patch service myapp-service -p '{"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Local"}}'

Next, configure the Ingress resource for IP whitelisting using the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range annotation:
example
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "123.123.123.123/32"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: myapp-service
            port:
              number: 1234


This configuration restricts access to the Ingress to the specified IP address 123.123.123.123 and will use IP whitelisting in Nginx Ingress for a public service, setting externalTrafficPolicy to Local and preserve the client IP.
Another way to restrict access to a publicly exposed service in AKS is you can use the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range annotation to whitelist a specific trusted IP. However, the default externalTrafficPolicy being set to "Cluster" can obfuscate the sender IP, even for the Ingress controller. To lift the source IP obfuscation without changing the externalTrafficPolicy, you can use the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/real-ip-header annotation to specify the header that contains the real IP address of the client. Set the value to X-Forwarded-For to use the X-Forwarded-For header.
example-
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "123.123.123.123/32"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/real-ip-header: "X-Forwarded-For"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: example-service
            port:
              name: http

This example uses the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/real-ip-header annotation to specify the X-Forwarded-For header as the header that contains the real IP address of the client. This allows you to lift the source IP obfuscation without changing the externalTrafficPolicy.
Using either externalTrafficPolicy: Local or the real-ip-header annotation with X-Forwarded-For approach to achieve IP whitelisting with Nginx Ingress in AKS are valid, and the choice between them depends on the specific requirements and network architecture.
References:

Similar Thread
Your Medium Doc
Use a public standard load balancer in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)
Maintain the client's IP on inbound connections


Hey, thanks for the response! I tried the
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/real-ip-header: "X-Forwarded-For" variant because it looks like exactly what I do want to find from first glace, but it doesn't appear to work. I'm getting 403 errors and correspondingly see cluster-internal IPs in the access logs.

And using external traffic policy method? I see you mentioned it works in comments. Yes, setting the externalTrafficPolicy to Local comes with potential downsides such as Load Distribution: Traffic is only sent to nodes with relevant pods or in case of pod failures, the service won't reroute traffic to other nodes unless a relevant pod is available on those nodes. But if you are trying this on test env then you can give it a shot

Of course I'm trying in test environment first. :)
The way you describe it, it sounds actually like there would be practically no impact or at most a very marginal scenario where it would actually make a slight difference in my use case.

@NaveenSharma : thanks! I thought I would copy Arco's post from the comments into "Answer your question" since that's what resolved/clarified it for me, rather than the main post. Since it doesn't seem to be possible to put a tick on the lower comment?
